# Access array elements ANSI SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, mongodb, apache-drill

I'm using Drill to query MongoDB using ANSI SQL , I have a field that contains an array of values, I want to be able to access those elements to join them with other documents .

```
select name from table where table.id = array.element;
```

but other than `FLATTEN` which divides them into multiple lines, I can't access the array's elements. 
Any help please ?

Comment: share some sample data from mongoDB collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some sample data in mongodb

```
db.col.insert({"id":1,name:"dev","arr":[1,2,3,4]});
```

Working query from Drill:

```
select name from col4 where id=arr[0];
```

Output:

```
+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| dev   |
+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you again, I marked it as an answer but actually what I needed was indented select (select inside select and Flatten for the array)

Comment: @Jean no need to accept the answer if it did not complete your query. Unaccept it and edit your question, add sample mongoDB data and expected SQL query.